# AWS IAM Role Access to Redshift:DescribeData

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, amazon-iam, serverless-framework

I despair of trying to get access to the redshift-data api from a aws lambda function, more specifically '`Redshift-data:DescribeStatement`. I can send BatchStatements but I cant receive them, I think it's the condition key that I don't really understand how it works.

The following is my IAM Role Policy:

```
{
...
    {
        "Action": [
            "redshift-data:BatchExecuteStatement"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:redshift:eu-central-1:____________:cluster:a-cluster-name",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Sid": "RedshiftExecutionAccess"
    },
    {
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "redshift-data:statement-owner-iam-userid": [
                    "*"
                ]
            }
        },
        "Action": [
            "redshift-data:DescribeStatement"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:redshift:eu-central-1:____________:cluster:a-cluster-name",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Sid": "RedshiftResultAccess"
    }
}
```

generated by the following serverless statement:

```
    ...
    - Sid: 'RedshiftExecutionAccess'
      Effect: 'Allow'
      Action: 'redshift-data:BatchExecuteStatement'
      Resource: 'arn:aws:redshift:eu-central-1:____________:cluster:a-cluster-name'
    - Sid: 'RedshiftResultAccess'
      Effect: 'Allow'
      Action: 'redshift-data:DescribeStatement'
      Resource: 'arn:aws:redshift:eu-central-1:____________:cluster:a-cluster-name'
      Condition:
        StringLike:
          redshift-data:statement-owner-iam-userid:
            - '*'
```

As said the BatchExecuteStatement passes, but the DescribeStatement fails and I am not sure the Condition-Setting is the problem at all. The Exception:

```
com.amazonaws.services.redshiftdataapi.model.AWSRedshiftDataAPIException: User: arn:aws:sts::____________:assumed-role/redshift-access-role/TrialUserImporter-dev-importer is not authorized to perform: redshift-data:DescribeStatement because no identity-based policy allows the redshift-data:DescribeStatement action (Service: AWSRedshiftDataAPI; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: 20a9533e-e4a1-4d0b-870b-ac15431e554f; Proxy: null)
```

Does anybody have an idea how I can fix this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Why do you have the condition?

Comment: It does not work without the condition with the same error, so I thought I have to define the Condition

Answer (score 3):

I used resource as "*" and it worked see snippet

```json
{
    "Sid": "DataAPIIAMSessionPermissionsRestriction",
    "Action": [
        "redshift-data:GetStatementResult",
        "redshift-data:CancelStatement",
        "redshift-data:DescribeStatement",
        "redshift-data:ListStatements"
    ],
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Resource": "*",
    "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
            "redshift-data:statement-owner-iam-userid": "${aws:userid}"
        }
    }
}
```

from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/redshift-iam-access-control-identity-based.html

Comment: You should wrap the code block with the language tag its written to markdown.